# dplyr::filter removes NAs when filtering for not equal to a value

Tags: r, dplyr

Is this expected behavior of `filter` in `dplyr`? Sounds horrendous. Am I missing something, or have the wrong version?

```
mydf <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = c(letters[1:3], rep(NA, 2)))
mydf
  x    y
1 1    a
2 2    b
3 3    c
4 4 <NA>
5 5 <NA>

filter(mydf, y != 'a')
  x y
1 2 b
2 3 c

packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.7.2’
```

Comment: The `filter` has been in that way for a long time  You may need `filter(mydf, y != 'a' |is.na(y))`  I just checked with `R 3..1.3` and `dplyr_0.4.3`
and it gives the same output as yours

Comment: OMG - I have no idea how many bugs I introduced in my code without realizing this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

It's right there in the documentation for `?dplyr` (although it seems like this was only added to the documentation [9 months ago](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commit/465cc2819116b654ed9d882f7fa6bc1cf2d96ece)):

> Use filter() find rows/cases where conditions are true. Unlike base subsetting, rows where the condition evaluates to NA are dropped.

This is consistent with the way `base::subset()` works, but *not* how subsetting with `[`+logical indexing works.

As @akrun says in comments, you can use `filter(mydf, y != 'a' |is.na(y))` to preserve `NA` values.  It would be nice to be able to use `identical()` or `isTRUE()`, but these aren't vectorized. You could write a convenience wrapper:

```
eq <- function(x,c) {x==c | is.na(x)}
filter(mydf,eq(y,"a"))
```